# Which one should I use: session vs _session in Pkcs11interop

Tags: c#, pkcs#11, hsm, pkcs11interop

I am facing the same issue as the owner of this thread:
[Threadsafe usage of PKCS11Interop library in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715797/threadsafe-usage-of-pkcs11interop-library-in-c-sharp)

Here you have provided a solution and given a link of https://github.com/jariq/Pkcs11Interop.PDF/blob/1.3.0/src/Pkcs11Interop.PDF/Pkcs11RsaSignature.cs

I have a small confusion, in this class I have seen many occurrences where you are using

```
using (Session session = _slot.OpenSession(true))
```

statement. However inside it, you are using the predefined variable `_session`, you are not using this `session`. 
But in the `Sign` method you are using this `session` instead of `_session`.
Please help, in which cases I should use `session` and `_session`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this. Local variable `session` should always be preferred. Field `_session` should be used only to keep the login state. I've fixed the code in commit [179003b](https://github.com/jariq/Pkcs11Interop.PDF/commit/179003b330aba353bd3bd1ccf9f03fe5d4fd9d8a) and [fixed class is available in master branch](https://github.com/jariq/Pkcs11Interop.PDF/blob/master/src/Pkcs11Interop.PDF/Pkcs11RsaSignature.cs).

Comment: Thanks @jariq  for you quick resolution you are always a saviour.

Comment: I have one more issue if you can help.
In my class I always log in into HSM in constructor and log out in dispose method.
However, if some exception comes in between it always starts throwing error that user is already logged in into HSM. My application is an multi threaded application. Please help what should I do.

Comment: In the catch block I have written session.Dispose() should I add session.Logout().
Or is there any method using which can tell me whether the user is already logged in. Then I can check and if he is not logged in then only I will call the Login method.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Kumar you can use `session.GetSessionInfo().State` to check whether it is a public or authenticated session.

Comment: Thanks a lot jariq